# CoCreateInstance hangs in console application

Tags: c, visual-c++, com, firefox-addon, stdin

The following is the short reproduce sample:

```
DWORD WINAPI _threadTest (LPVOID)
{
    Sleep (2000);
    CoInitialize(0);
    CoCreateInstance(...); // <---- hangs here
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize (0);

    CreateThread (0, 0, _threadTest, 0, 0, 0);

    uint32_t size = 0;
    fread (&size, 4, 1, stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

So. First of all, the problem happens under Windows XP only.

Secondly, this console application is really a part of Firefox browser extension. Extension communicates with it using stdin/stdout pipes.

Now the most interesting thing. The problem does NOT reproduce if this EXE is launched using cmd.exe (for example). It reproduces only in case its launched by Firefox browser.
The problem does NOT reproduce even if EXE is launched by Firefox in case I comment fread call and use Sleep (10000) instead of it.

The target COM component is in a separate process.

So, to "hang" CoCreateInstance we need:
1. Windows XP
2. Process launched by Firefox
3. Process' main thread locked by fread call.

What happens and what can be done here?

**Stack trace from my real application:**

```
Worker Thread   Win32 Thread    sxs.dll!__ioinit    Normal
ntdll.dll!_KiFastSystemCallRet@0()   
ntdll.dll!_NtQueryVolumeInformationFile@20()     
kernel32.dll!_GetFileType@4()    
sxs.dll!__ioinit()   
sxs.dll!__CRT_INIT@12()  
sxs.dll!DllStartup_CrtInit(struct HINSTANCE__ *,unsigned long,void *)    
sxs.dll!__SxsDllMain@12()    
ntdll.dll!_LdrpCallInitRoutine@16()  
ntdll.dll!_LdrpRunInitializeRoutines@4()     
ntdll.dll!_LdrpLoadDll@24()  
ntdll.dll!_LdrLoadDll@16()   
kernel32.dll!_LoadLibraryExW@12()    
kernel32.dll!_LoadLibraryW@4()   
oleaut32.dll!OaLoadLibraryAW(char const *,unsigned short const *)    
oleaut32.dll!GetRedirectionProcAddress(char const *,void * *)    
oleaut32.dll!MapIIDToFusionCLSID(struct _GUID const &,struct _GUID *)    
oleaut32.dll!ProxyStubCLSIDOfInterface(struct _GUID const &,struct _GUID *)  
oleaut32.dll!CPSFactory::CreateProxy(struct IUnknown *,struct _GUID const &,struct IRpcProxyBuffer * *,void * *)     
ole32.dll!CStdMarshal::CreateProxy(struct _GUID const &,struct IRpcProxyBuffer * *,void * *,int *)   
ole32.dll!CStdMarshal::MakeCliIPIDEntry(struct _GUID const &,struct tagSTDOBJREF *,class OXIDEntry *,struct tagIPIDEntry * *)    
ole32.dll!CStdMarshal::UnmarshalIPID(struct _GUID const &,struct tagSTDOBJREF *,class OXIDEntry *,void * *)  
ole32.dll!CStdMarshal::Finish_RemQIAndUnmarshal1(struct tagSQIResult *,struct tagQICONTEXT *)    
ole32.dll!CStdMarshal::Finish_QueryRemoteInterfaces(struct tagSQIResult *,struct tagQICONTEXT *)     
ole32.dll!CStdMarshal::QueryRemoteInterfaces(unsigned short,struct _GUID *,struct tagSQIResult *)    
ole32.dll!CStdIdentity::CInternalUnk::QueryMultipleInterfaces(unsigned long,struct tagMULTI_QI *)    
ole32.dll!CStdIdentity::CInternalUnk::QueryInterface(struct _GUID const &,void * *)
FmBrowserHelper.exe!_com_ptr_t<_com_IIID<IWGUrlReceiver,&_GUID_454a4044_16ec_4d64_9069_c5b8832b7b55> >::CreateInstance(const _GUID & rclsid, IUnknown * pOuter, unsigned long dwClsContext) Line 592
```

Microsoft Visual C++ 's fread implementation calls _lock_fh on zero handle (stdin) before locking the thread in _read_nolock call (trying to read from stdin). I suppose the problem is somewhere here... When main thread quits from fread - CoCreateInstance returns.

Comment: I've also created bugzilla report here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1186095

Comment: "what can be done?" First of all you need call stacks in the frozen process. It is unclear whether it's COM related freeze, or the object itself freezes during instantiation. Then apparently your main thread is not COM friendly/compliant: if you make it STA then you have to dispatch messages there and not do `fread`.

Comment: Unfortunately, call stacks does not contain any useful info because there are no symbols loaded for system's dlls for some unknown reason (I have licensed XP, but it's non-English, maybe it's the reason). No symbols for these dlls (remaining has): advapi32.dll, ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll.

Comment: I've tried MTA (CoInitializeEx (0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)) - does not make sense. And if this is the reason, why blocking Sleep call changes the behavior?

Comment: And why it works being launched from the command line shell?

Comment: OK, I refactored the code to process stdin/stdout in a separate thread. Main thread processes the messages queue. This did not help. But  I got a good stack trace. Will post it a bit later.

Comment: What is the callstack on the main thread at the point that it's hung?

Answer (score 0):

Cool work, I think you need to do:

```
CoInitializeEx(null, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
```

As was done here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Examples/Using_COM_from_js-ctypes

Comment: I do not use js-ctypes at all.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev bottom line is they are using `CoInitializeEx` there as well, that code works from ChromeWorker's which are other threads. Give it a shot can't hurt.

Comment: CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED) is the same as CoInitialize (0). Please do not waste my time. Just tried - did not help.

Comment: That Mozilla link is filled with inaccuracies, such as stating that *MSDN documentation says that even if CoInitalize fails, CoUnitialize must be called*, which is wrong, it says it must be called even if `CoInitialize[Ex]` returns `S_FALSE`, which is a **successful** return value.  Regarding shell functions, `CoInitialize` should still be used, because otherwise you're at the mercy of the `SH*` functions `CoInitialize`ing (or not) the thread for you.

Comment: Thanks very much @PauloMadeira for that! I'll make sure to update that, I'm not a pro at this stuff so just wrote from my understanding and what worked. By any chance would you be able to sign up for MDN to fix that? :) If not no prob i can do it :)